# How Filter data in a dataframe Pandas having a set of elements

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have a DataFrame with:

```
 A        B     C
 5670   'Inf' 'Geo'
 4673   'Inf' 'Geo'
 3452   'Inf' 'Geo'
 9837   'Inf' 'Geo'
 7846   'Inf' 'Geo'
```

and I have also a vector that should be used to filter the first dataframe
     vector=[5670,7846]
I would like to obtain in pandas a dataframe having the form:

```
  A        B     C
 5670   'Inf' 'Geo'

 7846   'Inf' 'Geo'
```

is there a function in pandas to do that easily?
thanks.

Comment: Doe you mean isin?

Comment: Yes, it should be. I'm using it but uses too much time to return the dataframe. is there another method faster?

Comment: Try converting vector to a set